# Mongoose _id full object comparison

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this doubt for quite some time:

When using mongoose, if i compare (on query) a mongoose object to an _id field, does the ODM is "intelligent" enough to realise that what i mean is to compare to the _id field.

The alternative is simple. Just map the object or array and get the _ids and then compare. This is what i have been doing so far. I have, however, run some tests to prove this. Mi results are pretty good: Yes it does...so far.

However I don't want to do it blindfolded. I found this in the mongoose docs:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-equals
But is, to my understanding, inconclusive to the actual behaviour of the comparisons.

Furthermore, how this affects (for example) the $in operator.
I don't know if my doubt is somehow clear. Just for the sake of it i am posting a code example.

```js
//Say we have this 2 schemas

var roleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type:String, unique:true},
  tier: Number
}};

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {type:String, unique:true},
  lastName: {type:String, unique:true},
  role: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Roles', default:null}
}};



//Now we have a set of fully populated roles
var _roles = ... //fully populated roles

//So if i want to query users..can i safely do something like this?
Users.find({role:{$in:_roles});

//Or should always map?
Users.find({role:{$in:_roles.map(r => r._id)});
```

Comment: There is an error on map it should be: `_roles.map(r => r_.id)`

Comment: You can [edit] your question to fix that typo in the map call. Anyway, I've noticed the same thing you're seeing where the `_id` from the doc is magically used, but I've never seen it documented clearly so I don't rely on it.

Comment: I found the edit!...i swear i looked for it. Yeah exactly, I dont rely on that either but i would be nice to dont have to map anymore.